# Convert CLLocationCoordinate2D to iphone/ipad coordinate system

Tags: ios, cllocation, coordinate

I am trying to convert the coordinates returned by cllocation manager and plot them on the ipad screen. i tried this but the points are not marked correctly

```
CGSize screenSize = _tilingView.bounds.size;
CGFloat SCALE = MIN(screenSize.width, screenSize.height) / (2.0 * EARTH_RADIUS);
CGFloat OFFSET = MIN(screenSize.width, screenSize.height) / 2.0;
CGFloat x = EARTH_RADIUS * cos(latLong.x) * cos(latLong.y);
CGFloat y = EARTH_RADIUS * cos(latLong.x) * sin(latLong.y);
```

_tilingview is my view on which i have a custom indoor map on which i want to show the users location

Answer (score 0):

This approach won't work because the Earth is not a perfect sphere - It doesn't have the same radius in both axes.  Also, degrees of latitude are non-linear - the [linear distance varies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system#Expressing_latitude_and_longitude_as_linear_units) depending on the angle due to the shape of the Earth - Maps look linear because they use a *projection* - typically the Mercator Projection - to project the surface of an (almost) sphere onto a flat surface .

There are some helper function in the `MapKit` framework to convert between geographic coordinates and view coordinates - `MKMetersPerMapPointAtLatitude` and `MKMapPointForCoordinate`.  There was also a good session at WWDC 2014 - '[Taking Core Location Indoors](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=708)' that covered these functions and how they can be used to convert from geographic coordinates to linear coordinates